# Read a string from shared preferences in flutter

Tags: flutter, sharedpreferences

I have saved two strings using shared preferences. I want to retrieve the strings individually and display it as texts.

Write:

```
_nameSaver() async {
    SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    prefs.setString('name', nameController.text);
    prefs.setString('school', schoolController.text);
  }

RaisedButton(onPressed: () => _nameSaver(),);
```

Read:

```
  _nameRetriever() async {
    SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    final name = prefs.getString('name') ?? '';
    final school = prefs.getString('school') ?? '';

    print(name);
    print(school);
  }
```

I should extract out the name and school from the shared preference and display it on the list tile respectively. Title for name and subtitle for school. However i am unsure on how to extract it this way using a method await.

```
ListTile(title: Text("") 
         subtitle: Text(""),),
```

Comment: haven't you fixed yet?

Answer (score 3):

First define to variables for the texts

```
String nameText = '';
String schoolText = '';
```

Assign these to Widgets

```
ListTile(title: Text(nameText) 
         subtitle: Text(schoolText),),
```

Now in read from sharedpref function set these

```
 _nameRetriever() async {
    SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();

setState(){
 nameText = prefs.getString('name') ?? '';
 schoolText = prefs.getString('school') ?? '';
}

    print(targetPrice);
    print(instrumentPair);
  }
```

**EDIT**

This is just to demonstrate how it works. I have made the save function a future function just to make sure I read after saving.. It's not need if you are doing saving and reading at the same time

```
class Home extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _HomeState createState() => _HomeState();
}

class _HomeState extends State<Home> {
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _nameSaver().then((_) {
      _nameRetriever();
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(body: Container());
  }

  Future<String> _nameSaver() async {
    SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    prefs.setString('name2', 'asdsadasd');
    prefs.setString('school2', 'asdasdas');
    return 'saved';
  }

  _nameRetriever() async {
    SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    final name = prefs.getString('name2') ?? '';
    final school = prefs.getString('school2') ?? '';

    print(name);
    print(school);
  }
}
```

Comment: but it returned me as an empty string for both

Comment: ```prefs.getString('name')``` returning empty string?

Comment: may be at the time you are saving, the text controllers are empty or something.. try my example and see if data is printed on log.. I could help if you can show the whole code

Answer (score -1):

Can Read value from pref. as -

```
getPref('name');
```

Using this method-

```
 getPref(String key) async {
        SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
        String auth = prefs.getString(key);
     }
```

Worked for me.

Comment: It says 'Future<dynamic> is not a subtype of type string'